# Why does WSO2 Identity Server retrieve tenant admin credential from a registry file not from a database?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to create a self-signup client application which is using WSO2 API Manager and Identity Server.

When I tried to call a web service provided by Identity Server, I've observed that some of the java classes are trying to get a tenant admin credential from a registry file called `self-signup.xml`.

Due to this I am forced to change the tenant's admin credential manually in `self-signup.xml` whenever I change the admin's credential through carbon UI.

My questions are:

1. Is there any specific reason that WSO2 Identity Sever gets a tenant admin credential from that registry file rather than retrieving it from a database?
2. Is there any way to automatically update the tenant admin's credential written on that registry file when the credential is updated in the database (e.g. changed through carbon UI)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is the web service you are using for self sign up here?

If you are using `UserRegistrationAdminService` you should not require any admin credential for self sign up.

You should not require to read admin credentials from a file in your client. Usually if you want to call a web service which require authentication from your client, you need an user logged in to your client and you need to use the cookie retrieved by that user.

Comment: I'm using UserRecoveryInformationService. Since verifyUser() service requires a tenant admin credential, I had to get it from somewhere.
While I was investigating it, I did some decompile on wso2 default java classes and found one of the classes is retrieving tenant admin credential by using the following code:

org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.SelfSignUpUtil.getSignupConfiguration(tenant_name);

So I copy that code and use in my client.

Comment: Why don't you use UserRegistrationAdminService ?

Comment: I'm trying to do this 

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recover+with+Notification, password reset.